# Redirect of all files to index.php in a subdirectory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a website under /var/www/v1 and /var/www/v2. In the v2 folder I have a .htaccess file with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1
```

The rewrite rule wont work under the v2 folder, but works fine if I put it and the files into the /var/www/ directory.

For example I have these files:

```
upload.php
display.php
index.php
```

When I got to website.com/v2/display/ it throws a 404 saying "The requested URL /v2/display/ was not found on this server."

Comment: I changed it to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /v2/index.php?request=$1` and it works now, but not if the file exists. For example, if I call `website.com/v2/something` it directs it to index.php with the request=something. If I go to `website.com/v2/display` I get the 404 saying the file does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to disactivate MultiViews:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /v2/index.php?request=$1 [L]
```